# Install my own software on VPS

Tags: apache, vps, iis

I didn't have VPS before, I wanna know can I install any software on VPS? For example if I buy Windows VPS can I install Apache on that instead of Microsoft IIS?

Comment: This is a question you should be asking your host

Comment: @Milad You would need full administrative privileges. If the VPS has a third-party control panel like Plesk, it's also possible to [reconfigure](http://kb.parallels.com/en/2151) it to use Apache, with an admin account.

Comment: If you want to run Apache, why buy Windows? Buy a Linux VPS

Comment: Because Windows is easier, I didn't work with Linux!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host allows it, and you have root access, you should be able to install anything you could locally. I know nothing about IIS but, on my FreeBSD host, I have full access to my system as if it were in the same room with me. Anything available for FreeBSD I can install on that but not all hosting companies are the same and some won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can install whatever you like on a VPS. [Wikipedia defines a VPS as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) "A VPS runs its own copy of an operating system, and customers have superuser-level access to that operating system instance, so can install almost any software that runs on that OS."

The only limitations are going to be choice of OS from the VPS provider and OS compatibility of the application with the OS. You might also check the licensing terms for proprietary software to make sure you are permitted to use it with your VPS, too.